# CSS direct descendant not working properly on production build

Tags: css, asp.net-core, webpack

I suspect this is an issue with webpack, but I cannot seem to get this to work. My only CSS file (main.css) contains the following code:

```
.numpad > input {
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    margin: auto;
}
```

However when I publish the application, the CSS file shows the following:

```
.numpad {
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    margin: auto;
}
.numpad > input {
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    margin: auto;
}
```

I have searched the entire solution for any sort of duplicate that could be causing the first. It doesn't exist.
My webpack config is as follows:

```
module.exports = (env) => {
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
    return [{
        stats: { modules: false },
        entry: { 'main': './ClientApp/boot.tsx' },
        resolve: { extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'] },
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, bundleOutputDir),
            filename: '[name].js',
            publicPath: 'dist/'
        },
        devtool: 'inline-source-map',
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.tsx?$/, include: /ClientApp/, use: 'awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true' },
                { test: /\.css$/, use: isDevBuild ? ['style-loader', 'css-loader'] : ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ use: 'css-loader?minimize' }) },
                { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000' },
                { test: /\.js$/, include: /src/, exclude: /node_modules/, use: { loader: "babel-loader", options: { presets: ['env'] } } }
    ]
},

plugins: [
    new CheckerPlugin(),
    new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
        context: __dirname,
        manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
    }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist'])
].concat(isDevBuild ? [
    // Plugins that apply in development builds only
    new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
        filename: '[file].map', // Remove this line if you prefer inline source maps
        moduleFilenameTemplate: path.relative(bundleOutputDir, '[resourcePath]') // Point sourcemap entries to the original file locations on disk
    })
] : [
        // Plugins that apply in production builds only
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
        new ExtractTextPlugin('main.css')
    ])
}];
};
```

Any ideas for why there is a duplicate being created?

Comment: First, make sure it's not a caching issue. Clear your cache, try with another browser etc.

Comment: Cleared the cache and also tried another browser. Same result.